# How to display webpages from a list one after another with pyqt4?

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, qwebview

I am trying to figure out how to display multiple webpages from a list one after another. So far in my code, I am traversing through the list, but I am doing this before I actually call app.exec_() so it only displays the last item. How can I make this work so it iterates through all the items in the list in the same window?

```
import sys, time
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

app = QApplication([])
view = QWebView()
view.setGeometry(100, 150, 1200, 600)
urls = ["https://www.google.com", "https://www.facebook.com/",    "https//:www.stackoverflow.com"]


for url in urls:
   view.setWindowTitle(url)
   view.load(QUrl(url))
   view.show()
   time.sleep(3)

app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your code doesnt' let the QApplication refresh.

When you call time.sleep(3) the code stop there and the QApplication can't refresh.

You have to place your QWebview in a QDialog and call the method QDialog.exec_()

instead of view.show().

```
import sys, time
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

app = QApplication()
dialog = QDialog()
view = QWebView(dialog)
view.setGeometry(100, 150, 1200, 600)

urls = ["https://www.google.com", "https://www.facebook.com/",    "https:www.stackoverflow.com"]


for url in urls:
   view.setWindowTitle(url)
   view.load(QUrl(url))
   dialog.exec_()

app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I think this is in the right direction, but so far the view only loads the next item when you close the window. I forgot to mention that I want it to iterate in the same window.

Comment: Ok so, You will have to go further and build an interface with a QPushButton and on signal clicked() of the button load the next page. You can find everything you need on Google. Signal connection and interface building.